# Qatar Airways says that sharp or point objects are not allowed on the aircraft

Tags: safety, hand-luggage, qatar-airways, cabin-crew

I emailed Qatar Airways to ask if I would be permitted to carry multiple pieces of jewellery (not real gold or silver) on board if some had pointy or sharp edges. They responded saying sharp objects are not permitted which could be injurious to others.

It's just jewellery and I don't want to put it in checked because some are gifts and some are just valuable and special to me. And I have no intention of hurting anyone and I don't see how a corner or point on jewellery will cause harm to others.

So would I not be able to take them on the aircraft or not? I dont want to get them taken off me. I have a bracelet and it is square in the middle with 4 points/edges, necklace has corners that are point or sharp, but not that sharp to cayse injury to someone. These are just some examples. Has anyone ever done this. I have taken jewellery before but I don't remember if it had a sharp point.

Also does anyone know the limit of taking jewellery on board or does it not apply in my situation as I am not carrying gold or silver.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have never flown with Qatar, so I can't comment on that, but no single airline has ever had any problems with my mini screwdriver that's on my keyring (for repairing glasses), or any of my jewellery.

Comment: Ultimately it will be security screening, not Qatar that will determine if your jewelry can travel or not.  So the policies of the country you are boarding in will be the deciding factor.

Comment: Realistically, you would have to post a picture of the item to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: @johns-305 I've described it which is more than enough....it doesn't have spikes of anything. Like I said it has like a spare design with for corners with a slight point. Qatar airways is saying that items with sharp edges aren't allowed I checked the website and it didn't say anything about jewellery it only said knives, blades etc which obviously I am not taking

Comment: I would err on the side of caution, either by putting them in checked luggage or not bringing them at all - as you say you don't want to risk losing them. I once brought a small nail clipper in my carry on, by accident, and it was confiscated. The rules don't tend to consider whether or not your intentions were good, so I wouldn't count on your jewellery being an exception to the rule.

Comment: @robyn I have to take them....I'm moving

Comment: @IramAhmed Hmmm. In that case, I see three options: carry on luggage, checked luggage, or post. All have a slight risk (either getting lost or confiscated), but the latter two you could insure.

Comment: @robyn i understand the airline wants the to be sure of the safety of passengers. But seriously? Come on first of all I wouldn't hurt anyone. Second of all I'm going to cause so much injury with earrings or a necklace....

Comment: @IramAhmed I completely agree with you... These rules are often not particularly reasonable, but they get applied regardless.

Comment: @robyn I agree.... although I looked on qatar airways website and it said sharp pointy objects such as knives and blades which I am not talking anyways, but it doesn't say anything about jewellery

Comment: As @Johns-305 said, it's hard to give useful advice without a better idea of what the objects look like. Could you do a Google search, find an image of something similar, and post it?

Comment: Ok guys I've posted a few pictures. I have a few occasions going on whilst I'm abroad which is why I'm taking tiaras and stuff

Comment: I don't see anything in those pictures which is sharper than, say, an ordinary house key, and those are certainly allowed.  I think you're fine.

Comment: @IramAhmed: saying "I have no intention of hurting anyone" is beyond pointless.

Comment: @tonyk ok....so.....and no its not pointless maybe for the wierdos at the airport but not for me. As I know what my intentions are....I've posted pictures so you look at them and see if they are 'sharp' or 'dangerous'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem with the item you have listed; and there are no limits to the number of articles of jewelry you can carry on-board - assuming they all fit in your hand luggage and your hand luggage does not exceed the allowances for carry-on luggage (which you can find [on the qatar airways website](http://www.qatarairways.com/kw/en/baggage.page)).

Personally speaking, unless you have a golden or silver knife, you will not have any problems. I have seen people wear multiple articles of jewelry, some even a large cross (which is more pointed than your samples) without issue.

The key thing is can it be used as, or confused for, a weapon.

Keep in mind that although there are no limits (other than the normal luggage limits), you may want to check what are customs regulations for your destination country.

Comment: You mean all the key necklaces?....all of them would cause a problem?